# mysql select union with limit used twice

Tags: mysql, limit

I have example query

```
select id from clients where email like '%a%'
union 
select id from clients where email like '%b%'
```

which works fine, but i need to add limits like

```
select id from clients where email like '%a%' limit 5
union 
select id from clients where email like '%b%' limit 5
```

but this breaks with

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union
select id from clients where email like '%b%' limit 5' at line 2
```

I made some tries and surprisingly

```
select id from clients where email like '%a%' limit 5
union 
select id from clients where email like '%b%'
```

works fine

I'm using oracle mysql 8. Any ideas what I do wrong ?

Comment: When ORDER BY and/or LIMIT applied to separate queries is present then each separate query must be enclosed with brackets. [UNION clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Comment: PS. LIMIT without ORDER BY gives non-deterministic result and hence makes no sense.

Comment: Your subject line says mysql, but you tagged both mysql and oracle.  Which is it?

Comment: @Akina, well if you need some test data to populate pdf report, you don't really care if it's deterministic

Comment: It's oracle?  But then you remove the 'oracle' tag and make the statement "I'm using oracle mysql 8"  MySQL is not oracle.  It is a totally different database product It just happens to be owned by the same company (Oracle Corp.) that owns the Oracle database.

Comment: I meant mysql owned by oracle and not mariadb, sorry for confusion